# java_cup cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, weka

I just installed weka in eclipse, and then I got the following java_cup error.

[image]

What should I do? Where can I get this java_cup so I can reference it as a part in the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

weka says everything it needs (at runtime) is in the weka.jar, but look for java_cup [here](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/)